# How to change background colour of Leanback SearchSupportFragment Android

Tags: android, leanback

How can I change background colour of search support fragment in android leanback library. I have tried to find a public function to do the same just like in BrowseSupportFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val backgroundManager = BackgroundManager.getInstance(requireActivity())
val backgroundManager.attach(requireActivity().window)
backgroundManager?.color = Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
```

It works for the RowsSupportFragment, so I guess it works for search too